# How to create own custom http request method in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Can we create custom http request in spring boot? We have already GET, POST, PUT etc.

Can we create "**customHttp**" request method and use them insted of those are already we have in spring boot. Is this possible in java or in spring boot?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/",method = RequestMethod.customHttp)
```

Comment: It's possible, but don't. Stick to the standard HTTP verbs. Everything that calls your service will have problems if you do this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...
I have XMLHttpRequest.open("someService", uri, true)

I am trying to call by rest temple in spring.

Whenever I call this I am getting 405 method not allowed [no body] error.

Comment: That doesn't sound like you need custom HTTP verbs. Perhaps you should ask a question about your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `RequestMethod` covers nearly all request types, that are defined in [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-method-definitions), except `CONNECT` which can be handled with other methods. If you want to create your own request type, you can try to go into `@RequestMapping` annotation to see how it works.

Edited: I do not recommend to do this, because of world RFC 9110 that was created especially for strict specs of HTTP/1.1

Comment: Thanks for your reply...
I have XMLHttpRequest.open("someService", uri, true)

I am trying to call by rest temple in spring.

Whenever I call this I am getting 405 method not allowed [no body] error.

Comment: Unfotunately, there is no such skill as "Second Side" in my superhero skill list)) Can you please share the code that is responsible for this endpoint coverage (i mean, from front- and backend at the same time)

Comment: What's more, `XMLHttpRequest.open()` has strict syntax https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open 
BTW, my recommendation is to use at least `ajax` lib for frontend (best, imho is `axios`)